# What happen if misaligned connect 6 outlet

Tags: electrical, receptacle

Mistake can happen, so because the design. Will the electricity work okay?
[image]

Comment: If the receptacles are fed by separate circuits that don't share a neutral it could trip any GFCIs.  It could also start a fire by overloading the neutral if two separate same phase lines ended up sharing it.  If they were separate circuits not on the same phase and one of the plugs was miswired(Another example of something that can go wrong but will still work), the load would be connected to 220/240V.

Comment: @KH that looks like a standard 120v setup are your 220/240 receptacles on the same format? The ones I worked with were much different.

Comment: @EdBeal almost all 120V setups are 120/240 or 120/208 systems, so in cases where more than one circuit/phase are present at the same location, miswiring can overload a neutral or present a 120V device with 208/240V.  I just wanted to point this out because the OP's example presents a fairly innocuous error when all receptacles are wired to one circuit, but there is still good reason to design plugs so this type of unintended connection isn't possible.

Comment: @kh as a professional electrician I have never seen a plug strip that matches your description. Yes I have seen 6 outlet , 3 on top 3 on bottom that could be part of a multi wire branch circuit connected to a duplex receptacle but never connected in the manor you suggest it would violate just a few code articles and 3rd party listing as required in the US not a chance.

Comment: @EdBeal I'm also a sparky but Canadian.  Pretty sure UL and CSA or other north american authorities wouldn't like these receptacle dimensions, but OP has not provided information about what terminals are available and whether the plugs can be wired separately.  I'm not sure which condition you haven't seen.  Wiring errors like line/neutral reversal are not that rare and examples where you may have multiple 120V circuits in one box are commercial installations in conduit or(in Canada anyway) older kitchen receptacles wired as split duplex with a shared neutral.

Comment: I think it's more likely to see this kind of poor design on for example a power strip that plugs into a single outlet, which negates the concern, so I haven't disagreed with the answer given that it would likely work, but I wanted to illustrate that although you can produce this unnecessary "feature" in the receptacle design, there are ways neighbouring receptacles can be wired that make it a bad idea in some cases.

Comment: @kh those plugs are power strips only 1 hot per horizontal set. We can play what if all day long but that is not what the op asked. Jasen has a good answer and explanation.

Comment: @EdBeal Have you actually seen these dimensions installed down in the states?  I have similar ones, but the dimensions don't quite match up so you can't plug in this way.  I guess if it's allowed it's allowed.

Comment: <cough> compulsory earth <cough> (Sorry, couldn't resist;)

Comment: I did a brief image search and only found pre-wired outlets like powerboards and surge supressors with this outlet pattern.

Comment: @jasen same as I said as a power strip maybe I should have said plug in. But er can let the internet only electricians keep answers and comments that have nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will work ok.  because only an ungrounded plug can be used backwards, and the wide pin stil goes into the wide slot etc.

Others have commented that this layout is non standard and it's unlikely that the device has been blessed by UL.

Comment: I haven’t seen one that the spacing were the same but agree, yes it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Underwriter's Laboratories (UL) is a testing lab who also writes the standards for what is allowed in the US market and those who rely on UL's standard making.  UL or competitor labs such as CSA, ETL etc. will not give their mark of quality to products which are not safe.

Of course for business and treaty reasons, direct mail (including via Amazon dropshop warehouses) bypasses that safety regime, and you can get all manner of junk from certain Asian nations.  Moral of the story: Don't buy electrical gear on Amazon lol.

If the item has a UL Listing or other NRTL, then they know about it and it's been approved anyway.  CE and CCC are not NRTLs.

Comment: How does one verify a "UL Listing"?

Comment: @Simon -- you take the *file number* off the listing label (E##### for electrical gizmos) and plug it into the search box [that UL provides for this purpose](https://iq.ulprospector.com) (you'll need to create a free account there to use it)

Comment: In what way is this an answer to the OP’s question? It’s simple and listed or not I believe Jason’s answer is a complete and comprehensive not a talk about listing agencies that really had nothing to do with the answer.  I may not have seen one with this spacing because I don’t allow them at my plant or my properties. If more receptacles are needed I add them.

Comment: This may not answer the question, but is certainly valuable information in many of the cases that the question may be asked.  It also verges on the edge of safety in component selection.  Rarely hurts to spread a bit of safety knowledge.  OP starts off with "Mistakes can happen", which makes the question "Is the design itself an avoidable mistake?" relevant alongside the specific question of whether it would work.  No harm in having both answers.

Comment: @EdBeal the question is "is this OK?"  The answer is we have people who make that determination, officially, to everyone's benefit.  Those are facts.    If you prefer Jason's "opinion" simply because you dislike me, then have fun with that.

Comment: Really it states what would happen in the question and would it work? Not is it ok . I don’t know you and have no opinion of you other than your internet only experience as a electrician shows.

Comment: Ed, the title says "what happen?" The English is so broken that it's hard to say what the intent is, could be called either way.